# property not working seemingly because it's an integer

Tags: java

Okay so this is the second problem I've encountered with my game. This is a text based game and also I want to increase points based on user's answers. I have another class that saves the game and the points in case the user wants to continue the game later. The game saves alright, but the points do not and I think it's because it's supposed to return an integer. But I have no idea how to fix this. Program doesn't even start as the error I get is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt... Thanks in advance!

MainGame

```
public class MainGame {

    public static GameSave gameSave = new GameSave();
    public static String user = "";
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String question;
    public static int relationshipPoints;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        question = gameSave.loadGame();
        relationshipPoints = gameSave.loadPoints();
        RelationshipPoints points = new RelationshipPoints();

        System.out.println("\n\t*** TEXT_GAME: FIRSTDATE ***\n");
        System.out.println("-You can exit the game at any time by typing 'exit'.-\n\n");

        while (true) {
            user = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (question) {
                case "4_Story2":
                if (user.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    System.exit(1);
                    break;
                }
                switch (user) {
                case "1":
                    System.out.println("\n\nIan is overjoyed!");
                    relationshipPoints++;
                    gameSave.savePoints(relationshipPoints);
                    gameSave.saveGame("4B");
                    question = "4B";
                    break;
                case "2": [...]
```

GameSave

```
public class GameSave {

    public static Properties prop = new Properties();

    public void savePoints(int points) {
        try {
            prop.setProperty("Save_RPS", String.valueOf(points));
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.prop"), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public void saveGame(String point) {
        try {
            prop.setProperty("Save_Point", point);
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.prop"), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public int loadPoints() {
        int p = 0;
        String line = "";
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.prop"));
            line = prop.getProperty("Save_RPS");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                prop.setProperty("Save_RPS", String.valueOf(p));
                prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.prop"), null);

                try {
                    prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.prop"));
                    line = prop.getProperty("Save_RPS");
                } catch (IOException exe) {

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }
        p = Integer.parseInt(line);
        return p;
    }

    public String loadGame() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.prop"));
            line = prop.getProperty("Save_Point");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                prop.setProperty("Save_Point", "0");
                prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.prop"), null);

                try {
                    prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.prop"));
                    line = prop.getProperty("Save_Point");
                } catch (IOException exe) {

                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }
        return line;
    }

    public void newGame() {
        try {
            prop.setProperty("Save_Point", "0");
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.prop"), null);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line you are getting java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Comment: Never, ever write an empty `catch` block.  Exceptions are an extremely valuable means of knowing when something has gone wrong, and exactly where it has gone wrong.  At the very least, each of your `catch` blocks should contain `e.printStackTrace();`.  Also, you need to close your OutputStreams.

Comment: Word. It's the programming equivalent of driving your car with a blindfold on.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels such a good metaphor.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels While everyone else does too!

Comment: As other's have said, in every one of your catch blocks, at minimum put "ex.printStackTrace()", and you'll narrow in on the real issue.

Comment: @Sundararaj Govindasamy this is the line that's giving me the error: relationshipPoints = gameSave.loadPoints(); which is related to GameSave loadpoints() and savepoints()

Comment: @VGR thank you, I had no idea! will do so from now on

Comment: With a quick look, you use `parseInt` once, so we know it's the `line` that's null, and you assign `line` in three places, one to an actual string (we know that's not null), and the other two assignments with method calls. That must mean one of those method calls doesn't work as expected for you, I would debug it and see what's wrong with your arguments or flow of execution.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove debugged it, says line's value is null. I have no idea why it's null, it's supposed to be either 0 or whatever points you have so far in the game (1,2,3...)

Comment: @Evan Did you debug into the `prop.getProperty("Save_RPS")` method calls that return null? Try inspecting the `prop` object as well, might be a flag that stands out. My guess is you don't actually have a property in that file that's mapped to the string `"Save_RPS"` (always consider your arguments as incorrect first when getting back a result you didn't expect from a method/function call, as that's the simplest mistake to make).

Comment: @NESPowerGlove you were right! that was it! thanks a lot man.